# Android: TableLayout Row Not Centering via XML

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to center a table row using XML in Android, but I'm having a problem where it's over to the right just a smidge too much for two of my rows that only contain two buttons. Here's my code, and I have a screen shot of how it looks

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hiragana_multiple_choice_main_image"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="30dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hiragana_multiple_choice_button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hiragana_multiple_choice_button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hiragana_multiple_choice_button_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hiragana_multiple_choice_button_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

http://www.ptrprograms.com/multiple_choice_offset.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to use LinearLayout instead of tablelayout, it will fix it to center and also use fillparent and wrap content for best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try these Way....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```